# How to deploy React three fiber app that has a .gltf model?

Tags: web-deployment, github-pages, gltf, react-three-fiber

I created a website using "create react app" and I have a model.gltf in my "public" folder, when I run npm run deploy it creates a "build" folder that has the model.gltf inside it but the github page throws:

On Chrome`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`

On Firefox `XHR GET https://marinakhamis.github.io/model.gltf [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 69ms]`

P.S: I refer to Marina_model_stand_draco as model.gltf for simplicity

Here's the link to my repo https://github.com/marinakhamis/three-app

model.js file (Auto-generated by: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx)
[image]

package.json
[image]

folder structure

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read How to Ask, as well as this question checklist. Also please learn how to edit your questions to improve them.